# Django Models Storing Multiple sensor floating points into one field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Currently going through Django training this is a beginner question. The extent of what I know about **designing** models below

`name=models.CharField(max_length=255)`

`status_text=CharField(max_length=255)`

`name:'bob'`

`status:'status'`

**My Question**
How do I update the fields for this model

`name: 'bob'`

`omg:'['3.5', '10.2', '15.4', '13.2']`

`name=models.Charfield(max_length=255)`

`status:models.Charfield(max_length=255)`

Is it still the same same type of model.

**Correct Json Outcome**

`{
   name:"kehlin",
   status:[3.76, 8.8, 9.9, 10.3, 14.5, 18.0]
}`

Comment: You can use a `JsonField`, or some databases allow `ArrayField`s, etc.

Comment: Generally, one does not store multiple values in a single column of a database.